# cURL output to file

Tags: windows, logging, curl, cmd

Is it possible to direct this output from cURL into a file?

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1354  100  1354    0     0  17358      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 17358
100 67081  100 67081    0     0  68171      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 4031k
```

I cannot find anything in `--help` that would indicate you can. `-o` just done the response from what I can tell.

I am just wanting to know if the request succeded and how long it took.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This output is sent to stderr. So, to get it all you need is redirect stream 2 (stderr) to a file as

```
curl -o responseFile.html http://www.somewhere.com 2> informationFile.txt
```

But, as your capture shows, times are not always included.

The better option to know if the request succeded and how long it took is to ask curl to output some internal variables. This is done with the `-w` switch. So, your command should look as

```
curl -o responseFile.html http://www.somewhere.com -w "%{response_code};%{time_total}" > dataFile.txt 2> informationFile.txt
```

That way, the response will go to responseFile.html (or whatever you need), the progress information (stderr or stream 2) will go to informationFile.txt and the required request response code and time information will go to dataFile.txt

Comment: I cannot get the response code to resolve, I just get the variable name.  Are you sure the syntax above is correct?  I have looked at the Curl help stuff but it is not very clear on DOS specifics.  For info, I am wrapping the curl call in a batch file, which might be something to do with it.

Comment: Ah, got it, In a batch file you need double percent ie -w "%%{response_code}".

Comment: How to save output to variable?

Comment: @Andrey, `for /f` command is the usual way to execute a command and process/retrieve it's output.

Answer (score 7):

This is what you need:

```
curl -o gettext.html http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html 2> details.txt
```

The above will save the url to `gettext.html` and curl details to `details.txt`.